# How WP guesses which ID to use for new post?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, auto-increment

I'm puzzled with the following. Say, post_ID of my last post is 100. Now I remove all posts from my WordPress blog and even clear all revisions and so on from database if any, so now I have nothing in my wp_posts and wp_term_relationship. I expect to get post_ID = 1 for a new post. But I get post_ID = 101. Looks like WordPress stores ID for next post somewhere, but I've already spent half a day trying to figure out: where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just an auto incrementing column in the MySQL database. MySQL is using an internal counter, it's nothing to do with WordPress.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

**Update**

To reset your post ids, run the following (substituting in your tablename):

```
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

Comment: Thank you, Adam. Is it possible to reset this counter?

Comment: Thank you so much. I had no idea about this option before. And you are right: that was a question about MySQL, not about WordPress at all. :)

Comment: To change it via CLI, just run the query above like you'd run any query via CLI